# Why is my convolutional neural network failing to classify user inputted images after having high accuracy in testing?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, python

My CNN was trained on the Kaggle A-Z Dataset and consists of:

```
      model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5),input_shape=(28, 28, 1), activation='relu'))
      model.add(Dropout(rate=0.15))
      model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
      model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))  # choose the best features via pooling
      model.add(Dropout(rate=0.15))
      # flatten since too many dimensions
      model.add(Flatten())
      # fully connected to get all relevant data
      model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
      # fully connected to get all relevant data
      model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
      # one more dropout
      model.add(Dropout(0.4))
      # output a softmax to squash the matrix into output probabilities
      model.add(Dense(26, activation='softmax'))
```

Data used was split into training sets and test sets. Oversampling was used to account of the unbalanced dataset. The final accuracy was over 95%. Therefore, I expected my program to be able to read alphabetical letters with ease so I loaded one in:

```
def predictImageFromDrive(model):
  imageLocation = filedialog.askopenfilename()
  #image_numpy = cv2.imread(imageLocation, 0)
  image_numpy = cv2.cvtColor(imread(imageLocation), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  #print(image_numpy.shape)
  #print(imageir.shape)
  imageir = image_numpy.reshape(28,28,1)
  #print(imageir.shape)
  test_image = np.copy(imageir.reshape((1, imageir.shape[0], imageir.shape[1], imageir.shape[2])))

  print(test_image.shape)

  prediction = model.predict(test_image)
  classification = np.argmax(prediction, axis=-1)[0]
  print(prediction)
  plt.imshow(image_numpy)
  plt.title("Classification: " + chr(ord('@')+classification+1))
  plt.show()
```

The model now seems to predict every letter that I put in as part of the same category. For example, if I input an image of letter V, it shall predict it as an A, if I input an image of letter B, it shall classify it as an A and so forth. Why is this happening?

Comment: Check the numerical representation in your prediction code with the prepared dat ain training. Is the range of values for each pixel similar?